# How can I generate the DbContext of Entity Framework Core if my SQL Server database is on AWS?

Tags: c#, sql-server, amazon-web-services, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

I am creating a project on C# with .NET Core using Entity Framework Core, but I have migrated my local database to AWS, and now that I am using the connection string of Entity Framework, it does not generate the context nor the entities of the database.

The connection string I am using is:

```
Scaffold-DbContext 'Data Source=[SERVER].rds.amazonaws.com,1433;
Initial Catalog=[DATABASE];User ID=[USERNAME];Password=[PASSWORD];
Encrypt=False;Trusted_Connection=true'
         Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
         -ContextDir DBContext -OutputDir Models
```

I am using .NET Core 8 and I had created a DBContext when I was using my Local SQL Server Database, but when I migrated the Database I deleted the DBContext to create another one new; the problem is that when I use the connection string on the Package Manager Console it says "Build failed" and did not create the DBContext. If someone knows what I should do, I will be really grateful for your help

Comment: Aside... `Trusted_Connection=true` means to use Windows Authentication. You should use either that or use SQL Login authentication (the `User ID` and `Password` parameters), but not both in the same connection string.

Comment: _does not work_ is not very helpful to people on the other side of the internet that cannot see your screen. Do you get some kind of error message?

Comment: You are right, my apologies for that
But the problem is that when I run the command on the Package Manager Console it only says "Build failed..."

Comment: "Build failed". Because the first thing these command line tools do is compile your current solution. And that failed. Check the build output and fix every error...

Comment: I'm not sure you can connect to aws by windows auth, it doesn't know anything about your domain i guess. Try writing a simple C# app creating sql connection with your connectingstring and see if it works first

Answer (score 0):

**I have found the solution**
As I previously had a DBContext, when I deleted it all the solution had problems so I needed to fix all those problems first (As someone recommended me on the comments) then, I tried running the Connection String again, but I needed to change some things:
Scaffold-DbContext 'Data Source=[SERVER].rds.amazonaws.com;Initial Catalog=[DATABASE NAME]; User ID=[USERNAME];Password=[PASSWORD];Encrypt=false;Trusted_Connection=true;Integrated Security=false' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -ContextDir DBContext -OutputDir Models

I added "Integrated Security=false" because it solve some connection problem with Management Studio and after that, it started to create all the Database Models and the DBContext from the AWS Server